# why the direct2d line and wpf line always take two pixel on the screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, direct2d

[image]

I have create a simple test for display this question, this is the demo code with C# winform:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.FromArgb(255, 41, 41, 41));

        float distance = 20;

        for (int i = 1; i < 25; ++i)
        {
            if (i <= 10)
            {
                using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.White, ((float)i) / 10))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new PointF(0, i * distance + 10), new PointF(this.Width, i * distance + 10));
                }

            }
            else if (i == 11)
            {
                using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 1.0f))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new PointF(0, i * distance + 10), new PointF(this.Width, i * distance + 10));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.White, i-11))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, new PointF(0, i * distance + 10), new PointF(this.Width, i * distance + 10));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the code use sharpdx do the same thing:

```
 private void renderControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            RenderTarget2D.BeginDraw();

            RenderTarget2D.Clear(new Color(41, 41, 41, 255));

            float distance = 20;

            for(int i=1; i<25; ++i)
            {
                if(i<=10)
                {
                    RenderTarget2D.DrawLine(new RawVector2(0, i * distance + 10), new RawVector2(renderControl.Width, i * distance + 10),
                        SceneColorBrush,
                        ((float)i) / 10.0f
                        );
                }
                else if (i == 11)
                {
                    RenderTarget2D.DrawLine(new RawVector2(0, i * distance + 10), new RawVector2(renderControl.Width, i * distance + 10),
                    FlagSceneColorBrush,
                    i - 10
                    );
                }
                else
                {
                    RenderTarget2D.DrawLine(new RawVector2(0, i * distance + 10), new RawVector2(renderControl.Width, i * distance + 10),
                        SceneColorBrush,
                        i - 11
                        );
                }
            }

            RenderTarget2D.EndDraw();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);
        }
    }
```

wpf test code:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(BackgroundBrush, BackgroundPen, new Rect(0, 0, Width, Height));

        float distance = 20;

        for (int i = 1; i < 25; ++i)
        {
            if (i <= 10)
            {
                Pen p = new Pen( myLineBrush, ((float)i) / 10 );
                drawingContext.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, i * distance + 10), new Point(this.Width, i * distance + 10));                    
            }
            else if (i == 11)
            {                    
                Pen p = new Pen(myFlagLineBrush, 1.0f);
                drawingContext.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, i * distance + 10), new Point(this.Width, i * distance + 10));
            }
            else
            {
                myLineBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);

                Pen p = new Pen(myLineBrush, i - 11);
                drawingContext.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, i * distance + 10), new Point(this.Width, i * distance + 10));
            }
        }

    }
```

please view this picture i have scaled it :
[image]

[image]

[image]
   you can see, the direct2d draw all the lines use two pixels, and gdi+ use one pixel.so it make the line which is drawed by direct2d looks like more thicker than gid+ lines.
   i have test this code in wpf and draw lines with DrawingContext, it has the same result with direct2d.
   i found there is a parameter in direct2d drawline function.

```
virtual void DrawLine(
             D2D1_POINT_2F    point0,
             D2D1_POINT_2F    point1,
             ID2D1Brush       *brush,
             FLOAT            strokeWidth = 1.0f,
             ID2D1StrokeStyle *strokeStyle = NULL ) = 0;
```

when i change the strokewith to less than 1.0, it only make the line dark,and not make it more thinner。
  so i want to know, how to change the default pixel width of direct2d/wpf lines? make it only take one pixel on screen like GDI+, thank you.

Comment: It looks like there's some antialiasing being done on the Direct2D version (see the grey pixels around the lowest white line in your last screenshot) - that can increase the rendered width of lines, try disabling it.

Comment: thank you, if i add 0.5f, it works.